# development loop for CLIPS

Tags: expert-system, clips

I'm a rank beginner to CLIPS expert systems shell.  I'm on Win7
I'm having trouble finding a good compile/test/debug loop.

To make the question really concrete, consider the animals.clp file that ships with CLIPS

When it thinks it knows what animal it is, it prints "I guess it is a "
What would your actions be to modify that to "I will guess it is a ", check that it
works with the new wording, and then change it to "I think it is a "

My current answer to this is 
modify file in external editor to "I will guess it is a "
start clips
load file with load menu or (load )
(reset)
(run)
exit clips
modify file to "I think it is a " 
start clips
load file with load menu or (load )
(reset)
(run)

Surely there's a way to avoid doing all this, but I can't seem to find a 'reload' command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to exit CLIPS. You can just issue the `(clear)` command (which has the same effect as exiting and restarting CLIPS), then `(load ) (reset) (run)`.

Comment: Thanks! I assume there's something like (do (clear) (load ...) (reset) (run))